# Meteor pass variable, iron route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Im getting started [Meteor](http://meteor.com) , I use iron router to manipulate route..
so I want to pass a variable to template:

```
Router.route('/foo', function(){
  this.render('foo', {name: 'Stack'});
});
```

how i can show the variable `name` in the template foo:

```
<template name="foo">
    <h2>Hi bro, how i can show the variable name here ?? </h2>
</template>
```

my project folder as the following structure:

```
/client
---/views
------foo.html
---/layout
------layout.html
/public
/server
```

layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

any solutions please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routing:

```
Router.route('/foo', function(){
  this.render('foo', {data: {name: 'Stack'}});
});
```

In your template

```
<template name="foo">
    <h2>Hi bro, how i can show the variable name here ?? </h2>
    <p>Like this --> {{name}}</p>
</template>
```

You can pull variables from the route too:

```
Router.route('/foo/:someName', function(){
  this.render('foo', {data: {name: this.params.someName}});
});
```

See [Iron Router docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can define a template helper to get the router name:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    name: Router.current().route.getName()
});
```

And then display in your template as:

```
{{name}}
```